# C++ std::transform() and toupper() ..why does this fail?

Tags: c++, string, stl, transform

I have 2 std::string. I just want to, given the input string:

1. capitalize every letter
2. assign the capitalized letter to the output string.

How come this works:

```
  std::string s="hello";
  std::string out;
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(out), std::toupper);
```

but this doesn't (results in a program crash)?

```
  std::string s="hello";
  std::string out;
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), out.begin(), std::toupper);
```

because this works (at least on the same string:

```
  std::string s="hello";
  std::string out;
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::toupper);
```

Comment: None of this examples compiles correctly in my case (gcc 4.7), i guess because `std::toupper` has been overloaded with a two arguments variant (provided by `locale.h`). I had to cast it explicitly: `std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), (int(*)(int))std::toupper);`

Comment: That's still unspecified behavior, since `toupper` isn't explicitly mentioned to be addressable.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There is no space in `out`. C++ algorithms do not grow their target containers automatically. You must either make the space yourself, or use a inserter adaptor.

To make space in `out`, do this:

`out.resize(s.length());`

[edit] Another option is to create the output string with correct size with this constructor.

`std::string out(s.length(), 'X');`

Comment: What's the difference between this and (Both are strings): std::string s2(s1); std::transform(s2.begin(), s2.end(), s2.begin(), std::toupper); ? Oh, I just answered my own question I think, in the first case it's just resizing the string. But in the second case I think it's equivalent?

Comment: See the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131858/stdtransform-and-toupper-no-matching-function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/ (though I will probably use resize myself for speed purposes)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that the iterator returned by `out.begin()` is not valid after a couple of increments for the empty string. After the first `++` it's `==out.end()`, then the behavior after the next increment is undefined.

After all this exactly what insert iterator is for.

Comment: Wouldn't .begin() equal .end() immediately for an empty string, rather than after the first increment?

Answer (score 0):

Thats the sense of a backinserter: It **inserts** elements to a container. using begin(), you pass a iterator to a empty container and modify invalid iterators.

I am sorry - my edits interfered with your comments. I first posted something wrong accidentally.

Comment: `std::transform` will apply the function on every character of the string.