# why the result is nothing for this code sample about string toupper?

Tags: c++, string

```
string str("fujian");
string newstr;
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), newstr.begin(), ::toupper);
cout << newstr << endl;
```

why the result is nothing for this code sample about string toupper?

Answer (score 3):

Your code writes past the end of `newstr` and therefore has [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Try either of the following instead:

```
// version 1
string str("fujian");
string newstr(str);
transform(newstr.begin(), newstr.end(), newstr.begin(), ::toupper);
cout << newstr << endl;

// version 2
string str("fujian");
string newstr;
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), std::back_inserter(newstr), ::toupper);
cout << newstr << endl;
```

Comment: There's also potential undefined behavior by calling `::toupper` with a `char` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got any space allocated for newstr.

See more here: [C++ std::transform() and toupper() ..why does this fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489313/c-stdtransform-and-toupper-why-does-this-fail)

Comment: but the newstr is "", isn't it?

Comment: @jiafu Read the link deepdownunder2222 provides. `std::transform` has no way to enlarge `newstr`, so it runs out of space.